# GCC: Random builds causing Segmentation Fault during execution

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, build

I'm currently struggle to unterstand a certain behavior which randomly happens after a software build. The software consists of multiple modules and, after building it, it will exit with a segmentation fault during execution.

I've identified two different steps during execution where this behavior happens.

1. The software exits with seg fault while executing a certain task.
2. The software exits with seg fault after completion of the task.

And in some cases, no seg fault occures at all. The problem is, that using a debug build, will only show me the cause of the second case (which is caused by a call to a third-party library). But I'm not really able to identify why this is happing.

It's a 32 bit build using gcc (SUSE Linux) 7.5.0.

Comment: Go back in the version control system until you reach a state when the crash doesn't happen. Then go forward checkin by checkin until it happens. Check the difference between the previous (working) and the current (non-working) checkin. And if you don't use a version control system, take this as a lesson to begin using one (and do all the rollback by hand).

Comment: I came up with this idea too but it seems somehow system related because no matter how far I go back in time, it still happens...

Comment: I understand that this is very specific, but could it be that a variable is declared by remains undefined? This may cause problems between runs, especially if it's used to access arrays.

Comment: Not much we can do without a [mre]

Comment: Yeah I know, but this would cause a different beavior in my opinion. If a variable is undeclared, it would depend on the value at the specific memory location and would cause, as you say, differences between runs. But the problem occures between builds which is quite strange. If a build does not exit with seg fault, it will never does this no matter how many runs one executes. But if a build shows this behavior, the seg fault will always occure.

Comment: @AlanBirtles: Actually this is not possible because it's a large non-open-source software...

Comment: Have you used static analysis tools to check your code-base? For example for possible use of uninitialized variables? Was there ever a time where these crashes didn't happen? What have happened since then? What have changed? Are you using new libraries? New versions of old libraries? Something else that have changed?

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, a lot can be learned from analyzing the release core dump (especially when built with `-g`). Analyzing environment and code differences is useful but nothing beats analyzing and debugging the bug itself.

Comment: The problem with those crashes is that they in general are caused by undefined behavior. And bugs causing undefined behavior could exist for a long time in the codebase without resulting in any noticeable problems or crashes that you might associate with that part of the code. A first step would be to increase the warning level of the compiler and use multiple compilers to build the code base and fix (not silence) those warnings. After that, you might need to use static analyzers, to do further checks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use valgrind to check your program for any memory issues